# delete object from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

need some help
I have an array like that

```
usernames=[
  username1{name : 'mark' , number : '10' , color:'green'},
  username2{name : 'jeff' , number : '15' , color:'blue'} ,
  username3{name : 'joy' , number : '30' , color:'yellow'}]
```

how to delete the whole line by object name (username1/username2)?

Comment: `usernames.splice(1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an object, then with

```js
var usernames = {
        username1: { name: 'mark', number: '10', color: 'green' },
        username2: { name: 'jeff', number: '15', color: 'blue' },
        username3: { name: 'joy', number: '30', color: 'yellow' }
    };

delete usernames.username2;
console.log(usernames);
```

Otherwise, if you have an array with objects, then with

```js
var usernames = [
        { username1: { name: 'mark', number: '10', color: 'green' }},
        { username2: { name: 'jeff', number: '15', color: 'blue' }},
        { username3: { name: 'joy', number: '30', color: 'yellow' }}
    ];

usernames.splice(1, 1);
console.log(usernames);
```

Comment: I wanna delete it by object id (username1/username2)

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
usernames.splice(1,1);
```

Removes the second element only.

The first parameter is the index of the item to remove, the second is the number of elements to remove.

[How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

**EDIT**

```
var index = usernames.indexOf(username2);
usernames.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: I wanna delete it by object id (username1/username2)

Comment: @Андрей_-_ Please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Use the `splice` method

```js
var usernames= [
  {"username1": {name : 'mark' , number : '10' , color:'green'}},
  {"username2": {name : 'jeff' , number : '15' , color:'blue'}} ,
  {"username3": {name : 'joy' , number : '30' , color:'yellow'}}]

usernames.splice(1,1);
console.log(usernames);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: I wanna delete it by object id (username1/username2)